# How to play Minecraft without a Microsoft account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Minecraft is a single player game. A Microsoft account was not required when I bought it. It's a requirement they added later. Asking your customers to do this years after the fact is unreasonable.

I don't want a Microsoft account and I'm not making one. How do I play my game?

Comment: "Asking your customers to do this years after the fact is unreasonable" Well yeah if it wasn't bought by Microsoft.

Comment: This is asked constantly. I don't agree with this solution, but something did have to change about the accounts. The number of hacked Mojang accounts i saw was absolutely insane, microsoft accounts have (mostly) eliminated this issue.

Answer (score 5):

**There is no other way to play Minecraft *officially* on that account** unless you link your Microsoft account.

Comment: Welcome to the site kickturn! As outlined in our [help section](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), suggesting piracy isn't permitted on Arqade. I've gone ahead and removed that part of your answer. Cheers!

Comment: @Wipqozn I'm not sure what you removed, but out of curiosity I looked through the answer history, and there was no changes to the text. The current text is the one posted initially.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Moderators have the ability to [hide/redact revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274274/157803)